# How to execute a library's Makefile from qmake

Tags: makefile, external, qmake

I have a Qt project and a subfolder `libparanoia` that has it's own Makefile (few `.mk`'s) and a RULES/conf folder.
When I execute `make` in the `libparanoia` folder it generates the `.o` files in a subfolder.

How can I, when I build my Qt application, run the makefile from `libparanoia` (a subfolder in the Qt project folder) and add the `.o` library to my Qt project (ok that's `LIBS+=`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to guess you will want to use [QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html#customizing) to do the work in your .pro file.

```
libpara_lib = <...some lib file...>
LIBS += libpara_lib


libpara.target = libpara_lib
libpara.commands = cd libparanoia && make -f Makefile

QT_EXTRA_TARGETS += libpara
```

Comment: but how can I clean it? "make clean" doesn't call the libparanoia's clean routine...

Answer (score 2):

Small correction: it's QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS not QT_EXTRA_TARGETS.

As for clean: add a custom clean target to your QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS:

```
libpara_clean.commands = cd libparanoia && make -f Makefile clean
```

This doesn't add that to the list of CLEAN dependencies; would love to know how to do that.